# Angularjs resource builds wrong resource url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

Resource:

```
angular.module('TicketService', ['ngResource'])
       .factory('Ticket', ['$resource', function($resource){
    var Ticket = $resource('/api/tickets/:id1/:action/:id2',
    {
        id1:'@id'
    }, 

    { 
        list: {
            method: 'GET'
        },
        listByOwner: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                action:'owner',
                id1:"@id"
            }
        }
        update: {
            method: 'PUT',
            params:{}
        }
    }); 
    return ticket;
}]);
```

Query:

```
$scope.userTickets = Ticket.listByOwner({
    id :  $rootScope.user.id
}, function(){
    //success
}, function(response){});
```

Result:

[image]

Angularjs builds a wrong url, `/api/tickets` but it should be `/api/tickets/2/owner`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure $rootScope.user.id isn't undefined?

Comment: @MarekTakac nope it was set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@` indicates that angular should look for the attribute on the data object, which is the second parameter (optional) in the Ticket service methods. In the first parameter you specify the request parameters. There are two ways you can fix this:

- Add an empty object as the first parameter

```js
$scope.userTickets = Ticket.listByOwner({},{
  id :  $rootScope.user.id
}, function(){
  //success
}, function(response){});
```

- Or rename the request parameter object key (from `id` to `id1`):

```js
$scope.userTickets = Ticket.listByOwner({
  id1 :  $rootScope.user.id
}, function(){
  //success
}, function(response){});
```