# Angularjs Resource URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm a beginner with AngularJS, and can't find my error in this code

```
   var myCarResource = $resource('cars/:carId', 
        {
            carId:'@id'
        });
    var car = myCarResource.get({id:'abc'});
```

Expected URL :
`.../cars/abc`

The called URL is: 
`.../cars?id=abc`

I'm using angularjs v1.2.24

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: May be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677487/angularjs-resource-builds-wrong-resource-url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the **[$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)** `paramDefaults` documentation:

> Given a template /path/:verb and parameter {verb:'greet',
>   salutation:'Hello'} results in URL /path/greet?salutation=Hello.
>
> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value for that
>   parameter will be **extracted from the corresponding property on the**
>   **data object (provided when calling an action method)**. For example, if
>   the defaultParam object is {someParam: '@someProp'} then the value of
>   someParam will be data.someProp

This suggests that any verb defined in the parameterizd url that matches the keys defined in the `$resource`'s parameter defaults or the `$resource` class methods(get, save, etc..) parameters will have the corresponding value of that key replace the verb in the url. The '@' notation on the other hand, was not explained properly in this context, it should have been:

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value for that
>   parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the
>   data object (provided when calling an **instance** action method).

Instance action methods($get, $save, $delete, etc..), are methods that are used for **data objects** retrieved using `$resource` class action methods. These are usually helpful when chaining  requests with the same resources.

**[EXAMPLE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/UEPmBqReotGX3Fay7R0e?p=preview)**

Let's assume that your `cars/abc` returns a response json of:

```
{
  "id": "abc"
}
```

Read the comments showing the responses of each action method invocation.

```
var myCarResource = $resource('cars/:carId', 
{
  carId:'@id'
});


// This sends a GET request '/cars/?id=abc
myCarResource.get({id:'abc'}); 

// This sends a GET request '/cars/abc'
myCarResource.get({carId:'abc'}); // returns {"id": "abc"}

myCarResource.get({carId:'abc'}).$promise.then(function(car) {

  // sends a POST request '/cars/abc', it replaces the :carId verb from the
  // @id notation you have defined in the parameter default. It also sends,
  // other parameter defaults defined with '@' that are defined as verbs in the url.
  car.$save();

});
```

Comment: From @Yalamber comment/link above, another option is to do the following: `myCarResource.get({},{id:'abc'});` From my limited understanding, I believe that the first object is directly related to the URL pattern, and thus must match the names of the :param in the URL (in this case, carId).  The second object is the one that is used when you use '@id'  and will pull the second object's ID and match it to :carId